# How long can I drive a company EU-registered car in the UK?

Tags: car, driving, company

I work for a German company and I am a resident in the UK working for the UK register branch. I drive a car in the UK for company and private use. This car is on EU registered number plates and is own by the EU (German) company.
How long can I use it for in the UK? 
Are there any other issues with doing so?

Comment: *Are there any other issues with doing so?* You mean, apart from Brexit throwing uncertainty into everything?

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer : If you become a resident or stay for longer than 6 months you must register and tax your vehicle in the UK

https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk/temporary-imports

Comment: The vehicle isn't his: it's his company's.  Therefore, it's the company's problem

Comment: @MatthewBarclay It's not necessarily that simple. I haven't found any clear statement of the rules in the UK to back that up in this particular case but in many European countries it is illegal driving *any* vehicle with foreign plates once you have become a resident. For example, it would be forbidden to drive a visiting friend's or family member's car if they are not present. Driving the vehicle might expose you to a fine and other unpleasantness if stopped by the police, no matter who it belongs to. (+1 to the answer)