# Moving to work to UK, can I drive my dad's EU-registered car in there for a while legally?

Tags: united-kingdom, driving, poland, vehicle-registration

As in the question, car is not mine and I intend to bring it back to EU after a few months when I get myself a new car, is that legal?

Comment: See [this other recent question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15901/how-long-can-i-drive-a-company-eu-registered-car-in-the-uk).

Answer (score 1):

No. If you become resident in the UK, you must register (and pay tax on) your vehicle within two weeks.

The police are very strict on this as there's a big problem with people registering cars in cheaper countries with less stringent roadworthiness rules, so you're likely to get the car seized if they spot you.

https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk/temporary-imports

Comment: And rest assured this is VERY true, I almost had my car seized but was let off with a warning and I had to go back and show the correct at the police station within 15 days after the warning.